# Correct way to say "N is in TOP-100"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

What would be the correct way to say that something was included in the top-100 list?

> 1. My university is rated in the top-100 best universities in the world.
> 2. My univrsity is in the top-100 best universities in the world.

Comment: You could just say " ... is one of the top 100 universities in the galaxy".

Comment: "top" and "100" are separate words, and there's no reason to put a dash between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Top 100 best" is redundant. "Top 100" is hyphenated when used as an adjective ("top-100 list") but not when discussing the top 100 of an item. You could say, for example,

- My university is rated as one of the top 100 universities in the world (or worldwide).
- My university appears in X's ranking of the top 100 universities worldwide.
- My university is one of the top 100 universities in the world, according to the list assembled by X.
- My university is a top-100 university (as ranked worldwide by X).
- My university is ranked in the top 100 in the world.